# How do I read/convert an HDF file containing a pandas dataframe written in Python 2.7 in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I wrote a dataframe in Python 2.7 but now I need to open it in Python 3.6, and vice versa (I want to compare two dataframes written in both versions).

If I open a Python2.7-generated HDF file using pandas in Python 3.6, this is the error produced:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`

If I open a Python3.6-generated HDF file using pandas in Python 2.7, this is the error:

`ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 4`

For both cases I simply saved the file by `df.to_hdf`.

Does anybody have a clue how to go about this?

Comment: How did you save the file? Please extend your question with the corresponding piece of code...

Comment: Looks to me like you ran into [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17540)

Comment: @BoboDarph hmm seems so. Too bad there's no definite solution! I cannot re-generate each file anymore so the solution suggested will not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a solution but more of a workaround.

I simply read the files in their corresponding Python versions and saved them as a CSV file, which can then be read any version of Python.

Comment: IMO mark it as Acceped. More people are bound to run into the issue before the powers that be decide to fix it and maybe this will spare hours of hair pulling

Answer (score 2):

Converting to CSV (proposed by @irenemeanspeace) will not work if some columns of the original dataframe contain lists or dicts.

I have found a workaround which can deal with simple objects like lists and dicts.
Convert it to json in py27 and then read it from py3.6.

```
# Run this in py2.7
###################################################
import pandas as pd
# read dataframe in py2.7
path = 'df.hdf5' # path to dataframe saved in py2.7
df = pd.read_hdf(path)
json_string = pd.to_json(compression='gzip')
with open('df.json.gz', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(json_string)


###################################################
# Now run in py3.6
###################################################
import pandas as pd
with open('df.json.gz', 'r') as fp:
    json_string = fp.read()
df = pd.read_json(json_string)
```

This is more general solution.